# How should we deal with OPs that edit in answer to question

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

It was discussed at [Putting found answer in OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155173/putting-found-answer-in-op) that you should answer the question with the solution, not edit that information into the question. But that discussion failed to cover what to do when you come across one.

I have come across questions that have no answer, but the OP put the answer in the question, such as [Silverlight 4 StringFormat for double without decimals in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338902/silverlight-4-stringformat-for-double-without-decimals-in-xaml). When I find those, I am tempted to edit that out and put it as an answer instead. But I would feel bad about taking any rep that came across my answer, and I would rather not put it as community wiki. Commenting didn't work in this situation, and it is easy to forget about it. So I'm stumped.

I have also come across questions such as [Image sprites not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458991/image-sprites-not-displaying#17458991), where the question was answered, the OP accepted an answer, and edited the solution into the question. I think it would be appropriate to edit this out, but I'm not sure.

---

[What should I do about a question where the OP has quoted an answer in the question but not accepted it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136955/what-should-i-do-about-a-question-where-the-op-has-quoted-an-answer-in-the-quest) is a similar question. But at that question, the OP edited into his question that both answers were good answers. Mine is what to do when the OP puts the actual answer to the question into the question

[What should be done with questions that have been self-resolved as a comment instead of an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-to-do-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-instead-of-a) is about the answer being a comment. Mine has nothing to do with comments